# Getting moving average from different groups in an unbalanced panel data

Tags: r, moving-average

I have this panel data that varies according to countries, years and groups. A same country in the same year can have data for different groups, or not. The panel is not balanced, so it does not cover the same time span for each country or each group.

For simplicity, the data looks something like this:

```
library(tibble)
df <- tibble(
  country = c("ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "ARG", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA", "BRA"),
  group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "A", "A", "A", "A"),
  year = c(1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1990, 1991, 1992, 1993),
  value = c(346, 573547, 534, 4645, 454, 3453, 64, 75, 346, 3465, 46, 876)
)
```

```
country group  year  value
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 ARG     A      1990    346
 2 ARG     A      1991 573547
 3 ARG     A      1992    534
 4 ARG     A      1993   4645
 5 ARG     A      1994    454
 6 ARG     B      1992   3453
 7 ARG     B      1993     64
 8 ARG     B      1994     75
 9 BRA     A      1990    346
10 BRA     A      1991   3465
11 BRA     A      1992     46
12 BRA     A      1993    876
```

What I'm trying to do is get a new column with moving average of 2 periods for each group in each country using value data. How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to compute the rolling average within a by group, you could do:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df |>
  mutate(ma = rollmean(value, 2, na.pad = TRUE, align = "right"), 
         .by = c(country, group))
```

**Output**

```
   country group  year  value       ma
   <chr>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
 1 ARG     A      1990    346     NA  
 2 ARG     A      1991 573547 286946. 
 3 ARG     A      1992    534 287040. 
 4 ARG     A      1993   4645   2590. 
 5 ARG     A      1994    454   2550. 
 6 ARG     B      1992   3453     NA  
 7 ARG     B      1993     64   1758. 
 8 ARG     B      1994     75     69.5
 9 BRA     A      1990    346     NA  
10 BRA     A      1991   3465   1906. 
11 BRA     A      1992     46   1756. 
12 BRA     A      1993    876    461
```

Answer (score 1):

Implement a straight-forward rolling function and apply it using `ave`

```r
rollmeanr = \(x, k, ...) {
  stopifnot(is.numeric(x), is.integer(k))
  res = rep(NA, length(x))
  for(i in seq_along(x)) 
    if(i >= k) res[[i]] = mean(x[(i-k+1L):i], ...) # ~"right-aligned"
  res
}
df$rm = with(df, ave(value, country, group, FUN = \(x) rollmeanr(x, k = 2L)))

   country group year  value       rm
1      ARG     A 1990    346       NA
2      ARG     A 1991 573547 286946.5
3      ARG     A 1992    534 287040.5
4      ARG     A 1993   4645   2589.5
5      ARG     A 1994    454   2549.5
6      ARG     B 1992   3453       NA
7      ARG     B 1993     64   1758.5
8      ARG     B 1994     75     69.5
9      BRA     A 1990    346       NA
10     BRA     A 1991   3465   1905.5
11     BRA     A 1992     46   1755.5
12     BRA     A 1993    876    461.0
```

It is not clear from your question, if you additionally need to account for potential `year` gaps. If a simple *for-loop* is not fast enough, have a look at [`{roll}`](https://github.com/jasonjfoster/roll):

```r
with(df, ave(value, country, group, FUN = \(x) roll::roll_mean(x, width = 2)))
```